# Multiple log files from different modules in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I've three different modules, let's call `ModuleA`, `ModuleB` and `Common`. The `Common` module contains some helper methods that are required by both `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`.

I wanted to have separate log files maintained for each modules, that means, there should be `ModuleA.log` and `ModuleB.log`. So in each module I've created a logger object with file handler and with the corresponding file names.

Now the problem is, if I call a method in `Common` from `ModuleA`, the log events in `Common` should be added to `ModuleA.log` and if I call a method from `ModuleB`, the log events in `Common` should be appended to `ModuleB.log`. For this, currently I'm passing a corresponding `logger` object as a parameter on the method from `Common` module which I feel is not a good solution.

Is there any way / patter to handle this scenario?

Comment: This may not be ideal depending on what the files contain, but if you can turn the important parts of `Common` into a class to inherit from, I guess you could override `self.logger` in each of the other two classes.

Comment: @Peter I got you. But what if I have some common decorators and wanted to use those decorators in the `ModuleA` or `ModuleB`?

Comment: That actually gave me an idea, I'll put an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a cache dict in `Common` that the other modules will be able to import and modify.

Here's a quick example with strings:

**Common.py**

```
CACHE = {'logger': None}

def func():
    print(CACHE['logger'])
```

**ModuleA.py**

```
from Common import CACHE, func

CACHE['logger'] = 'mod a'

func()
#mod a
```

**ModuleB.py**

```
from Common import CACHE, func

CACHE['logger'] = 'mod b'

func()
#mod b
```

If it feels a bit messy using a dict, I think you could potentially make a class to deal with the specific bits you need, it just needs to update in place instead of setting new values.